# ccavenue iframe integration in php

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, ccavenue

I need the payment within website using iframe.
I have a link for source code in image for iframe integration which is included in ccavenue integration payment gateway pdf But i dont understand that what source code explain ?
Anyone explain what flow explain from image ? Below image link 
what indicate this path "/transcation/jsp/iframe/iframeEncReq.jsp?" in below image.

[click here](http://postimg.org/image/7e16q0o21/) for image link for ccavenue iframe integration.
 
**Anyone explain how to ccavenue iframe integration in php from  image link**
how to integrate ccavenue iframe in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to download `PHP_Kit` from the Integration section.

In the PHP_kit you will find the `IFRAME_KIT` with the code needed for iframe.

You can use this [link](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/487006/IFRAME_KIT.zip) to download to `IFRAME_KIT`.